# Is there any cross-reference between Aku no Hana and Inside Mari?

Tags: the-flowers-of-evil, inside-mari

They supposedly share the same universe, but is there any element from one series referenced in the other?

Isao Komori is from the same region where Aku no Hana happens (and is the birthplace of both series' creator). Is it the only link, or is there anything else?